# How to set timer control in ajax javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, timer

Hai my application is tried to communicate with server,so i called the webservice in ajax,now i want to set the time interval in ajax.anybody indly guide me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").attr("disabled", true);
    //waitingDialog({});
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        var imei2 = '';
        imei2 = device.uuid;
        checkConnection_inonload(imei2);
    }

    function checkConnection_inonload(imei2) {
        var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
        alert(networkState);
        var states = {};
        states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
        if (states[networkState] == 'WiFi connection') {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "http://xxxx/Service1.svc/GetKeepMeStatus",
                data: {
                    IMEINO: imei2
                },
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (r) {
                    //closeWaitingDialog();
                    //alert(r);
                    if (r == "status") {}
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i set timeout in my ajax function `timeout:3000` Its working now.